# qgis2threejs navigation Android

Tags: qgis, android, zoom, qgis2threejs, tablet

The navigation of a 3D qgis2threejs map for an Android tablet is not optimal. Test on 7 and 10 zoll.
Problem: If I want to zoom in or out with **two fingers** the zoomlevels are to big. It should be small zoom levels. In this time the map is very difficult to handle. 
One finger for rotation and three fingers to move the whole map are OK.
Any idea to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution myself.
Open the file "orbitconrols.js".
Change

```
this.zoomSpeed = 1.0;
```

to

```
this.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
```

in row 77